# Is it safe to swim at Clifton Beach, Pakistan?

Tags: health, beaches, pakistan, swimming, karachi

[Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Karachi#Beaches_and_waterfronts) says of [Clifton Beach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifton_Beach,_Karachi):

> This was the world's most popular silver-sand beach and health resort throughout the 20th century, but it was affected by an oil spill in 2003 when the Greek registered oil tanker MV Tasman Spirit ran aground and over 12,000 tons of oil spilled into the Arabian Sea in what is considered by some to be the largest environmental disaster in Pakistan's history, so it is better take a stroll rather than swim in the sea because of polluted sea water and strong currents.

I suspect the info might be out of date. 14 years after the spill, is it still a reason to avoid swimming there?

Besides the spill, how bad are currents and other circumstances that may affect tourist swimmers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the cleanest beach but it's clean enough to swim. However, depending on the season (June to August is particularly bad), the currents may be too dangerous to swim.

There are other better beaches to consider. Hawke's Bay and Sandspit are 45 mins away. French Beach is the cleanest but you would need to ask someone with a membership and rent/borrow their beach hut.

Further ahead, Gaddani and Pasni beaches are also worth considering.

Comment: section 144 (ban on swimming in the sea) is imposed on the beaches around holiday times (Eid, Christmas, Independence day etc.) and during summer months also. So try to keep away from the water if there is police around, else you may have to bribe your way out of this sticky situation